# How to solve this error in Android Studio regarding :app:checkDebugAarMetadata?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

When I am running my application code i am getting following error in console

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> 2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

```
   1.  Dependency 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-29.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   2.  Dependency 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-29.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have tried many solutions but not able to solve this problem with correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Open file **`build.gradle.kts(Module :app)`** and change the compileSdk

from

> ***compileSdk = 29***

to

> ***compileSdk = 33***